# Grab Text from Div Using jQuery when Div name isn't unique

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there a way to grab the text content of a div based on it's position?

```
    <div class="locationDetailsRight">
   <div class="shiptoexpanded">
      <div>3 / 15</div>
      <div group-key="Shipping 12/2/2020">
         <div class="shipSort">20201202</div>
         12/2/2020
      </div>
      <div group-key="">$53.11</div>
      <div group-key="">$159.33</div>
      <div group-key="">$11.10</div>
      <div group-key="">$170.43</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to grab $159.33 and $170.43.

I write:

```
console.log($(".locationDetailsRight .shiptoexpanded").text())
```

And get back:

```
    "
          3 / 15
          
             20201202
             12/2/2020
          
          $53.11
          $159.33
          $11.10
          $170.43

"
```

Is it possible To grab the text on the lines that I need?

Comment: nth-child is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nth child selector https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

For your code, following will work

```
alert($(".shiptoexpanded").find(':nth-child(4)').text());
alert($(".shiptoexpanded").find(':nth-child(6)').text());
```

Here is JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/eqam8vbg/1/

Comment: Curious, why `:eq(0)`? What's the purpose? I've not worked with jquery deeply, just wondering when it is best to use it.

Comment: @Pirate It is not required, I was checking and forgot to get rid of it.